# Classified Envelope; What can this item be used for?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I just got the compendium full, and it gave me a Classified Envelope. It says that it has a photo of a young Sheikah inside.

What can I do with this? Does it contiune on another quest, or is it just a reminder that you completed the compendium?

Comment: So far, everything I've found about it ranges from being a pointless item or an item for a DLC in the future. Many have speculated that it triggers so sort of dialogue with Impa about a birthmark, but this has been disputed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most of the 100% completion "quests", the key item you get at the end is just proof that you've done it and serves no other purpose. It is similar to the item you get from Hestu for finding all of the korok seeds or the medals you get from Kilton for defeating all of the minibosses.