# Compendium completion

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

As fun as it is playing as Hyrule's version of David Attenborough, what benefits does having a complete compendium give, aside from allowing more precise tracking?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304183/classified-envelope-what-can-this-item-be-used-for

Comment: Don't forget to take a photo of the bosses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a lot of sites ([ZeldaInformer](http://www.zeldainformer.com/heres-the-weird-item-you-get-for-completing-the-hyrule-compendium-in-breath-of-the-wild/) for example), completing the compendium unlocks a dialogue with **Symin** at the Ancient Tech Lab.

He then gives you a '**Classified Envelope**' with 'a picture of a beautiful young woman of the Sheikah tribe in it.'

No one knows what it is used for right now, but some expect it to be useful in a future DLC.